# SQL updating master table with updates from update table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update my master table from my updates table, What it wrong with the below query.

```
UPDATE       master_table
SET          master_table.description = master_table_import.description
FROM         master_table_import
WHERE        master_table.user_id = master_table_import.user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a join between the tables. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE mt SET mt.Description = mti.Description
FROM master_table mt
INNER JOIN master_table_import mti
ON mt.user_id = mti.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always good idea to use aliases for tables. To update you have join your target table with source table:

```
UPDATE       mt
SET          description = mti.description
FROM         master_table mt INNER JOIN master_table_import mti
WHERE        mt.user_id = mti.user_id
```